# How do you convert a date in XSLT2.0?

Tags: xslt-2.0, formatdatetime

How can I format the resulted date below to display like this: MM/dd/YYYY (e.g.: 05/04/2020)?

The $getField will be: `2020-05-04T15:00:12`

My value in the template is:
`<xsl:value-of select="xs:dateTime($getField)+xs:dayTimeDuration('PT1H')"/>`

Currently, it displays as follows: `2020-04-05T16:00:12`

Each time I try using format-date, I get an error.
Also, if I will use `xs:date(xs:dateTime($getField)+xs:dayTimeDuration('PT12H'))`, it will display only the date, without hours/minutes, but still not sure how can I change the order for date?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at the specification of `format-dateTime` https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#function-format-dateTime? Which arguments have you tried, which errors exactly did you get? It might be hard to remember the details but looking at the examples in https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#date-time-examples and adapting them should be a good starting point.

Comment: Thank you! The examples are very useful, did not find that page before, I am still new with XSLT2.0.
I tried initially like this `format-date(xs:dateTime($getField)+xs:dayTimeDuration('PT12H'),'[M]/[D]/[Y]')` , and the error was that first argument of format-date needed to be date. 
Then, I realized that I needed to change to date only my value. It works fine like this:  `format-date(xs:date(xs:dateTime($getField)+xs:dayTimeDuration('PT12H')),'[M]/[D]/[Y]')`
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`format-dateTime()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#function-format-dateTime) function with the desired picture "[M01]/[D01]/[Y0001]":

```
format-dateTime(xs:dateTime($getField)+xs:dayTimeDuration('PT1H'), "[M01]/[D01]/[Y0001]")
```